# Passing LWA token to Cognito

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, login-with-amazon

I am working a an app which uses the Alexa Voice Service and maintains different users, so the users needs to login with Amazon (LWA). I have implemented it like it is written in the docs and it works flawlessly.

LWA docs: https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/login-with-amazon/use-sdk-ios.html

```
AMZNAuthorizationManager.shared().authorize(request, withHandler: {(result : AMZNAuthorizeResult?, userDidCancel : Bool, error : Error?) -> () in
            if error != nil {
                // Handle errors from the SDK or authorization server.
            }
            else if userDidCancel {
                // Handle errors caused when user cancels login.
            }
            else {
                // Authentication was successful.
                // Obtain the access token and user profile data.
                self.accessToken = result!.token
                self.user = result!.user!
            }
        })
```

Furthermore I need to retrieve information from DynamoDB, which uses Cognito for authentification. As stated in the docs, there should be a way pass the access token form LWA to Cognito, but I can't find the proper place to do it. They say LWA provides an AMZNAccessTokenDelegate, which it does not. The delegate method provides an API result which Cognito needs. The link in the Cognito docs below refers to the same exact link from the LWA docs I posted above.

Cognito docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon.html

```
func requestDidSucceed(apiResult: APIResult!) {
    if apiResult.api == API.AuthorizeUser {
        AIMobileLib.getAccessTokenForScopes(["profile"], withOverrideParams: nil, delegate: self)
    } else if apiResult.api == API.GetAccessToken {
        credentialsProvider.logins = [AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.LoginWithAmazon.rawValue: apiResult.result]
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

[EDIT]

I crawled through the LWA sources today until I finally found the correct delegate method.

Use AIAuthenticationDelegate instead of AMZNAccessTokenDelegate

But that lets me sit in front of the next two problems:

I.

```
Value of type 'AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider' has no member 'logins'
```

Maybe I have to use the following?

```
.setValue([AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.LoginWithAmazon.rawValue: apiResult.result], forKey: "logins")
```

II.

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey'
```

What do I put here? Maybe the API key I got from LWA?

[EDIT2]

I wanted to try it out, but `requestDidSucceed` never gets called, even through I successfully logged in.

Comment: posted on dev forums as well
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/92736/passing-lwa-token-to-cognito.html

Comment: Wow, still no response. Did you manage to get a solution?

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore and can't quite remember how I did it. I'm not sure, but I could just have set the DynamoDB table to public to try it out. It worked and I left it this way since it was just a proof of concept..

Comment: Thank you @dayd3amer for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomIdentityProvider: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager {
    func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
        return AWSTask(result: loginTokens)
    }

    var loginTokens : NSDictionary
    init(tokens: [String : String]) {
        self.loginTokens = tokens as NSDictionary
    }   
}
```

in the Authorization code at this below in successsful

```
    AMZNAuthorizationManager.shared().authorize(request) { (result, userDidCancel, error) in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                // Handle errors from the SDK or authorization server.
            } else if (userDidCancel) {
                // Handle errors caused when user cancels login.
            } else {
                let logins = [IdentityProvider.amazon.rawValue: result!.token]
                let customProviderManager = CustomIdentityProvider(tokens: logins)
                guard let apiGatewayEndpoint = AWSEndpoint(url: URL(string: "APIGATEWAYURL")) else {
                    fatalError("Error creating API Gateway endpoint url")
                }
                let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USWest2, identityPoolId: "IDENTITY_ID", identityProviderManager:customProviderManager)
                let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest2, endpoint: apiGatewayEndpoint, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    }
```